# Extend AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore (V2.1.3)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I simply want to extend the userstore and add extra method. I'm not able to define the correct constructor the customuserstore. How do I define constructor

```
public class MyCustomUserStore<TUser> : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore<TUser>, IUserLdapStore<TUser>
    where TUser : class
{
    // constructor goes here

    public Task<string> GetDistinguishedNameAsync(TUser user)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(string.Empty);
    }
}

public interface IUserLdapStore<TUser>
    where TUser : class
{
    /// <summary>
    /// When implemented in a derived class, gets the DN that should be used to attempt an LDAP bind for validatio of a user's password.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="user"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    Task<string> GetDistinguishedNameAsync(TUser user);
}
```

Getting following errors:

> The type '`TUser' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'UserStore'.
>
> There is no implicit reference conversion from 'TUser' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser'.
>
> 'TUser' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'UserStore
>
> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'context' of 'UserStore.UserStore(DbContext, IdentityErrorDescriber)'

Answer (score 1):

Going through the error message carefully you seem to be missing to add the constraint for `TUser` that forces it to inherit from `IdentityUser<string>`. This is an inherited constraint from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore<TUser>`.

Adding that constraint to your custom store is something like:

```
public class MyCustomUserStore<TUser> : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore<TUser>, IUserLdapStore<TUser>
    where TUser : IdentityUser<string>, new()
{
    //constructor goes here....

    public Task<string> GetDistinguishedNameAsync(TUser user)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Thanks to @KirkLarkin for pointing the second error I completely overlooked.

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'context' of 'UserStore.UserStore(DbContext, IdentityErrorDescriber)'

The error is a little cryptic, but it's easily solvable if we provide a constructor for the custom store providing the parameters for the base class:

```
public MyCustomUserStore(DbContext context, IdentityErrorDescriber describer = null) : base(context, describer)
{
}
```

Putting all these together, the class should look like this:

```
public class MyCustomUserStore<TUser> : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore<TUser>, IUserLdapStore<TUser>
    where TUser : IdentityUser<string>, new()
{
    public MyCustomUserStore(DbContext context, IdentityErrorDescriber describer = null) : base(context, describer)
    {
    }

    public Task<string> GetDistinguishedNameAsync(TUser user)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: My TUser is defined as this: public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>

Comment: @user10658716 if that's the case, it seems that you'll have to do a lot more than just inheriting from `IdentityUser<int>`. You should definitely take a look at these: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.1, http://johnatten.com/2014/07/13/asp-net-identity-2-0-extending-identity-models-and-using-integer-keys-instead-of-strings/.